# Gstreamer camera stream not working with h264 compression

Tags: video, streaming, video-streaming, gstreamer, h.264

I'm trying to stream from a local camera in `/dev/video0` over a local network compressed with h264.

When I send with:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

And receive with:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96" ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

The testimage works fine.

But when I try to send from the actual device `/dev/video0` with:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device="/dev/video0" ! video/x-raw,width=300,height=200 ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

I don't get any errors from the sender, but no image is displayed on the receiver.

Any suggestions what might be the problem?

Comment: do you see the output when displayed localy with autovideosink? do you use GST_DEBUG=3 at least(env variable)?

Comment: @otopolsky Do you mean if I see the stream piping directly from the device to autovideosink like: 'gst-launch-1.0 -v --gst-debug-level=3 v4l2src device="/dev/video0" ! autovideosink
' Yes I do. And I just set debug level to 3.

Comment: what about adding a queue element after v4l2src ? if you didnt find anything useful put GST_DEBUG=4 and check logs like "streaming stopped", also check the part where the preroll is happening

Comment: @otopolsky The queue didn't change anything. And as far as debug comes I'm not sure what to look for. I don't receive any errors or warnings.

Comment: I think you have to copy the caps exactly as they appear on sending pipeline and paste them to udpsrc caps string.. also you can try to set tune=zerolatency to x264enc but I think the problem may be in the caps..